# consensual VERSUS consentaneous - SYNONYMS?

Tags: meaning

> The relationship was consensual.
>
> The relationship was consentaneous.

Do they mean the same?

Comment: No.  They don't.

Comment: OK, they don't and what? What's the difference?

Comment: That's not how you spell 'synonyms'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: user1425 is a *learner*.

Comment: So, what the difference? sexual activity is consensual/sexual activity is consentaneous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main<sup>1</sup> difference is that ***consentaneous*** has [virtually no currency today](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consentaneous%2Cconsensual&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) compared to ***consensual***...

[image]

...but note that the former term *was* the most common one until the mid-1800's. So you could say it carries whatever associations you make alongside "dated" (old-fashioned, formal/official, etc.).

---

<sup>1</sup> Broadly speaking, both words mean "relating to consent / consensus". But both morphologically and semantically, ***consentaneous*** leans towards ***simultaneous*** (multiple parties reaching agreement *at the same time;* [***concomitant***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concomitant)).

I'd normally suggest checking out written occurrences of both words to get a feel for how they're used differently. But in this case, for a *learner*, the simplest advice is to just forget about the older term. You won't need it.